# Performance Testing ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, performance

I want to test performance of ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 based applications. I tried GDBT but it not give me any information about request time etc. I tried also a Workflow Profiler, but this tool usually crash my ArcMap installation. I think about use of ArcPy but I am not sure how to do that properly.

Any Ideas? Maybe someone of you made this kind of tests. For Manual tests I can use AutoIT but I am  not sure what use for loading tests of ArcGIS Desktop. And how to get any queries which are send by ArcMap to Database?

Answer (score 3):

There is no special Esri software for testing specifically ArcMap, but there some guidelines applicable for general software performance testing. This is called [System Design Strategies](http://esripress.esri.com/bookresources/index.cfm?event=catalog.book&id=1) and there are some tools and videos available online for free at Esri website as well as [wiki online](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/System_Design_Strategies).

I would also suggest looking at some major software methodologies for application performance testing generally.

[HP Load Runner](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1175451#.UR88IGfAF8E)
[Silk Performer](http://www.borland.com/products/silkperformer/)
[Visual Studio Test Team Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243146%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Check also Esri Enterprise guidelines on testing at the [Resource Center](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/enterprisegis/10.0/performance_testing).